# Dependency with different connection string

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection

I have problem with Unity. The connection string with DbContext is different because our system is using User in database to authenticate. 
How can I inject DbContext after user login successfully? I mean I would like to change user/password in connection string.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far?  If you have tried injecting different dbContext, please paste your code so we can see if you have any bugs in your code.

Comment: Unity the old Microsoft dependency injection library, or Unity the game framework (aka Unity3d)?

Comment: I already fixed the issue but it seems stupid code.

Comment: container.RegisterType<DbContext>(new TransientLifetimeManager(),
                new InjectionFactory(
                    c => new OPEntityContainer(GetOPEntityContainer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OPEntityContainer"].ConnectionString)))
                );

Comment: static string GetOPEntityContainer(string connectionString)
        {                                  
            var identityClaims = (ClaimsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                         userName =  identityClaims.FindFirst("Username").Value;
                password = SecurityHelper.DescryptParams(identityClaims.FindFirst("Password").Value, userName);
          
            return string.Format(connectionString, userName, password);                     
        }

Comment: Any suggesstion???